# Abrir un Modal luego de location.reload() con Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo un modal para actualizar datos. Al momento todo funciona, pero lo que quiero es que al momento de guardar datos, hacer un `location.reload();`, pero además, que vuelva a abrir el susodicho modal.

Dejaré la parte del ajax

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: api.dc_url + "profileUpdate",
    cache: false,
    method: "PUT",
    data: JSON.stringify({nickname, dirtycode}),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getCookie('k8495'));
    }
 }).done(function (response) {
    showLog(['sent message', response]);
    toast("✅ Success ✅");
    location.reload();
    
    //Por acá es cuando quiero que haga dicho reload y carga de un modal
    
 }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    toast("❌ Error ❌");
    api.functions.handleError(xhr, status, error);
 });
```

Comment: y porque si lo pones en el `$(document).ready(function(){})` , cuando cargue la pagina se abrira el modal

Comment: Por que no corre un una .ready, si fuera asi seria mas simple. @David081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer que al recargar se mande un parámetro y que en tu código se verifique si ese parámetro existe, y de ser así se ejecute la alerta:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: api.dc_url + "profileUpdate",
    cache: false,
    method: "PUT",
    data: JSON.stringify({nickname, dirtycode}),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getCookie('k8495'));
    }
 }).done(function (response) {
    showLog(['sent message', response]);
    toast("✅ Success ✅");
    window.location.href=window.location.href+"?alert=true";
 }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    toast("❌ Error ❌");
    api.functions.handleError(xhr, status, error);
 });

 const parameters=window.location.search;
 const urlParams=new URLSearchParams(parameters);
 if (urlParams.has('alert')) {
    toast("✅ Success ✅");
 }
```